# compare two cells on same row in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Using C# .NET 4.5, MS visual studio 2012, WPFs.

Hi, just got this code to finally work, it basically iterates through a datgrid via row.

be warned his may offend all the WPF wizards out there!

```
public IEnumerable<System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow> GetDataGridRow(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid grid)
{
    var itemsource = grid.ItemsSource as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
    paretogrid.UpdateLayout();
    if (null == itemsource) yield return null;
    foreach (var item in itemsource)
    {
        var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow; // null?
        if (null != row) yield return row;
    }
}

private void ShowArrows()
{
    var rows = GetDataGridRow(paretogrid); // fetching null?

    foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)
    {
        DataRowView rv = (DataRowView)r.Item;      
    }
}
```

So as you can see I iterate through the rows.  Now what I want to do is compare a cell value at column index 2 with columns index 4 on every "row", then if true or false update column 5 accordingly. I can iterate through the columns which lets me go cell per cell but isn't what I am after e.g

```
foreach (DataGridColumn column in paretogrid.Columns)
```

So is it something like:

```
paretogrid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(something here) as textblock;
```

Comment: Steven if you are already on that `row` I don't see why it is that you can't just check the value of the `rows column[4] for example by it's index` are you familiar with the `Quick Watch` you can play around with the `rows[rowindex].columns[columnIndex]` to evaluate the data value(s) that's just pseudo code example by the way

Comment: yes I'm play ing with grid.columns[2].getcellcontent(..)  so far it works but conversion does not , example if im comparing 2 ints when i convert to int 32 it cannot convert a textblock to int, so currently trying to see a way around it. I thought ied post this question to see if there is a different way I missed that's much simpler.

Comment: you need to `Convert the TextBlock.Text` not the Object itself Steve try doing that.. also can you show the code of how you are doing the convert it would much easier for me or someone else to give you the correct syntax.. `+1` for showing some positive effort by the way..

Comment: also I think that you would want to assign a `var` `to hold the value(s) that you are wanting to compare, convert, then assign back to the TextBlock.Text value`

Comment: yeh i originally had vars in, then swapped to ints and tried to force it to convert on the same line, turns out that was a bit "derpy" of me. so i changed it back to vars then converted the vars after to ints, wseems to be looking good

Comment: yeh works fine, Ive been wresling with WPFs all day trying to come to terms with it being a winforms guy, that i miss the most simple things at times!, ill update with an answer

Comment: ok let me make it easier for you to understand
`TextBox` for example if I did `var myInt = `(int)textBox1.text` for example this would compile because I am `implying that I want `myInt` to store an Int32 value, however `var myInt = (int)textBox1` would fail because you can not convert an Object, which is the `TextBox` to a `Value` does this make it easier to see where your initial `error is an why you were getting it`

Comment: yes i ignored what the textblock was and tried to convert it (an object) to an int... should have been .text added a solution to this question with regards to yourself for slapping me awake lol, cheers DJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see the following explanation below it will help clear up why you are seeing what you are seeing

Ok let me make it easier for you to understand TextBox for example if I did:

```
var myInt = (int)textBox1.text;
```

for example this would compile because I am implying that I want `myInt` to store an `Int32` value, however :

```
var myInt = (int)textBox1;
```

would fail because you can not convert an `Object`, which is the `TextBox` to a Value does this make it easier to see where your initial error is an why you were getting it.

This also has nothing to do with `WinForms` vs `WPF` if basically something simple that I am sure many of us have done before because we forget to Append `.Text` to the end of the object when we are wanting to convert the `Value` that the object holds rather that the object itself

Comment: exactly right, missed the obvious while over thinking about a WPF equiv of Winforms...silly me, thanks DJ!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I over thought this. here's the solution I had,

```
var test1 = paretogrid.Columns[7].GetCellContent(paretogrid.Items[2]) as TextBlock;
int t1convert = Convert.ToInt32(test1.Text);
var test2 =  paretogrid.Columns[8].GetCellContent(paretogrid.Items[2]) as TextBlock;
int t2convert = Convert.ToInt32(test2.Text);

if (t1convert == t2convert)
{
    MessageBox.Show("it worked!");
}
```

Thanks for pointing this out @DJ KRAZE

Comment: You're welcome, I left you an explanation so that if would make more sense. also `+1 for being able to quickly understand` what I was explaining earlier.