# Finding duplicate column values in gridview-Optimal Way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to find if two cells of different rows in a gridview have the same value or not.
I used this code but for millions of record, it takes much time. Can you tell me an optimal way ?

Can anyone also suggest me an optimal way

Comment: You will need integer index of the `Cells`, I think you can reference a Cell based on column name

Comment: here is a similar question look at how the OP figured out the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813266/compare-two-cells-on-same-row-in-datagrid

Comment: @Habib thank you very much. 
If there are millions of row, then this approach would take much time. Could you tell me which approach should i take ?

Comment: @devamwaah, why you want to have million rows in a Gridview ? If you have so many records then implement your logic at database end.

Comment: @Habib I was asked in an interview that if there are millions of record then what logic would you use

Comment: It would be lot easier if you would use little script (js or jquery) to do the job. Showing millions of rows in a gridview is not optimal, do some data filtering or pagination.

Answer (score 0):

There's the -1 missing in grv.Rows.Count in the 'otherRow' for statement.

```
public void HighlightDuplicate(GridView grv)
{
    //use the currentRow to compare against
    for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < grv.Rows.Count - 1; currentRow++)
    {
        GridViewRow rowToCompare = grv.Rows[currentRow];
        //specify otherRow as currentRow + 1
        //This forloop loops over more rows then exist
        for (int otherRow = currentRow + 1; otherRow < grv.Rows.Count -1; otherRow++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = grv.Rows[otherRow];

            bool duplicateRow = true;
            //compare cell ENVA_APP_ID between the two rows
            if (!rowToCompare.Cells["ENVA_APP_ID"].Text.Equals(row.Cells["ENVA_APP_ID"].Text))
            {
                duplicateRow = false;
                break;
            }
            //highlight both the currentRow and otherRow if ENVA_APP_ID matches 
            if (duplicateRow)
            {
                rowToCompare.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```